# php creating thumbnail on multiple file upload and saving both thumbnail and image in two different directories

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

I am trying to upload multiple images to a folder in my website.  While the file upload works without a problem, I am trying to integrate creating thumbnail for all the images uploaded in the same function which is not working.

**HTML Form:**

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-left"  action="fileupload.php" name="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;padding:5px 0 0 0;font-weight:normal" title="Add Images">IMAGES</label>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple id="file"><br>
      </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function _id(e) {return document.getElementById(e)}    
_id('file').onchange = function() {
  var theFile = this.files;
  if(theFile.length === 1) {
    var uploader = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = new FormData();
    file.append("file", theFile[0]);
    uploader.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(uploader.readyState === 4 && uploader.status === 200) {
        show_message('Uploading Image');
        console.log(uploader.responseText);

      }
    }
    uploader.open('POST','fileupload.php',true);
    uploader.send(file);
  } else {
    var start = 0,
    setter,
    buff = true;
    setter = setInterval(function() {
      if (buff === true) {
        show_message('Uploading Images');
        buff = false;
        var uploader = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var file = new FormData();
        file.append('file', theFile[start]);
        uploader.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(uploader.readyState === 4 &&  uploader.status === 200) {
            console.log(uploader.responseText);
            start++;
            buff = true;
          }
        }
        uploader.open('POST','fileupload.php',true);
        uploader.send(file);
      }
      if(start >= theFile.length) {
        clearInterval(setter);
      }
    }, 200)
  }
}
```

**fileupload.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$database = $_SESSION['folder'];
$match = $_SESSION['matchLst'];
$tardir = "/var/www/html/projects/" . $database . "/" . $match . "/";
$thumb = $match . "_thumb/";
$thumbdir = $tardir . $thumb;

function createThumbnail($filename) {
    if($filename) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($tardir . $filename);
    }
    $x = imagesx($im);
    $y = imagesy($im);

    $nx = 100;
    $ny = 100;

    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
    imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nx, $ny, $x, $y);
    if(!file_exists($thumbdir)) {
        if(mkdir($thumbdir)) {
            imagejpeg($nm, $thumbdir . $filename);
        } else {
            die("Thumbnail directory could not be created");
        }
    } else {
            imagejpeg($nm, $thumbdir . $filename);
    }
}


if(!isset($_FILES['file'])){die();}

if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    if($_FILES['file']['name']) {
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $source = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $target = $tardir . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
        createThumbnail($filename);  
        echo "Images uploaded";
    }
}
?>
```

I am facing 2-3 problems:

In the fileupload.php file if I comment out the `createThumbnail($filename)` then I am able to upload multiple files without a problem.  When I include createThumbnail function, neither file upload nor thumbnail creation happens.  I have tried various examples given here and git - however, not able to create thumbnail nor save it on to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

**$tardir** is not set here :

```
function createThumbnail($filename) {
    if($filename) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($tardir . $filename);
    }
```

You should replace your function call :

```
createThumbnail($filename);
```

By :

```
createThumbnail($tardir . $filename);
```

And don't use $tardir in your function.

Be careful when you set an absolute path :

```
$tardir = "/var/www/html/projects/" . $database . "/" . $match . "/";
```

Your script will be broken if the path changes. Instead you can use [magic-constants like **DIR**](http://php.net/en/realpath) and/or [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Thank you.  I tried adding `$tardir` to the createThumbnail call..but still it is not working.  However, When I removed all the codes from createThumbnail function and just echoed the filename, then all the files that were selected got echoed.  And again, when I add createThumbnail function, i could upload only one image, whereas when I remove I could upload all the selected images